# Clicking one button fires both buttons' Jquery methods

Tags: jquery, button, methods, click

I really don't know what to make of this.  I have two buttons, right next to each other, like so:

```
<div class="half">
    <label class="half">
        End Date:
        <div class="btn_contain">
            <input type="button" id="btnWeek" value="-1 Week" /><!-- THIS ONE... -->
            <input type="button" id="btnMonth" value="-1 Month" /><!-- ...AND THIS ONE -->
        </div>
        <input type="date" id="txtEndDate" name="end" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day')); ?>" />
    </label>
    <label class="half">
        Start Date:
        <div class="btn_contain">
            <input type="button" id="btnToday" value="Today" />
        </div>
        <input type="date" id="txtStartDate" name="start" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for the elements:

```
.half {display:block;}
.half:nth-child(even) {float:right; margin-right:0;}
.half:nth-child(odd) {float:left;}
.btn_contain {float:right;}
input[type="date"] {width:100%; display:block;}
```

And now for the javascript:

```
formatEndDate = function(date){
    var day = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    $('#txtEndDate').val(year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
}

$('#btnWeek').click(function(){
    var lastWeek = new Date();
    lastWeek.setDate(lastWeek.getDate() - 7);
    formatEndDate(lastWeek);
});

$('#btnMonth').click(function(){
    var lastMonth = new Date();
    lastMonth.setMonth(lastMonth.getMonth() - 1);
    formatEndDate(lastMonth);
});
```

Now, the problem here is this:

1. for whatever reason, the "-1 Month" button gets rendered to the LEFT of the "-1 Week" button... logically, it should be the other way around right?
2. Clicking the "-1 Week" button does what it's supposed to do, but if you click the "-1 Month" button first fires off the month button's click method, followed immediately by the '-1 Week" button's method (I verified this using console.log()).  So upon clicking it, it appears that it's only deducted a week from the "Start Date" field's value.

What is causing this behavior, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Setting up a jsfiddle.net example of this will inevitably lead to better answers.

Comment: I'm guessing your one button is actually covering your other button because of your floats. Inspect the elements and make sure that's not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `label` elements to `span`s or something else.  `label`s have special functionality relating to `input` and this is causing your issue.

Comment: yup - beat me to it by a min or so. For verification: http://jsfiddle.net/tWL28/1/

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!  Instead of changing the labels to spans or something else, I added the "for" attribute to the label, tying it to the date field itself.  And that fix worked just as well.

I would have never thought to look at the labels themselves.

Comment: Just be aware that the buttons being inside of the label mean that clicking on the button is also clicking on the label.  So clicking on your buttons will likely fire a click on your input as well.  This may have implications depending on your other code and/or browser.